# Download file with the name from last part of directory referred instead of real file name using wget or curl(Wget is prefered)

Tags: linux, curl, download, command, wget

Lets say,

`http://mobile.example.com/vid/flying-birds` 
is a page on which a link `http://mobile.example.com/vid/22` exist,
when we click on this link, 
it redirects to `http://v-cdn-r.example.com/mp4/x/y/dfile.mp4?ir=880&int=06` and the file with the name **dfile.mp4?ir=880&int=06** is downloaded.

i want to have this file name **flying-birds** (from first page url). i have tried doing this with wget function,

```
--default-page=name
```

with command

```
wget -r -l1 --default-page=name http://mobile.example.com/vid/flying-birds
```

but the downloaded file name is now **22** (from 2nd link) instead of my expected **flying-birds**

> i have more than one links and each link has different keywords
>   than **flying-birds.** in simple, there is lots of directory with
>   different-different directory name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
wget -r -l1 -O $(basename http://mobile.example.com/vid/flying-birds) http://mobile.example.com/vid/flying-birds
```

See this post for [How to wget a file with correct name when redirected?](https://superuser.com/questions/301044/how-to-wget-a-file-with-correct-name-when-redirected).

Comment: you solution is working great for a single action... but how to do if `i have more than one links and each link has different keywords
 than **flying-birds.** in simple, there is lots of directory with
 different-different directory name. i.e. **flying-birds** varies for each directory`